# How to log empty Mono

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Lets say I have the following lines

```
repository.findUser(name = "John Doe")
    .map {
        // User was found, continue processing
    }
    .switchIfEmpty(
        // Just log that the user was not found
    )
```

My non-best-practice-but-working approach currently is to just put the logging in another function and call it, like `switchIfEmpty(userNotFound())`

```
private fun userNotFound(): Mono<out Disposable> {
    logger.info { "No user was found." }
    return Mono.empty()
}
```

This works but I cannot imagine this is what I should be doing. How can I improve?

Comment: All the `doOn…` operators are for side-effects like for instance logging… try one of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the `Mono.defer` inside `switchIfEmpty`:

```kotlin
repository.findUser(name = "John Doe")
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer{ ... })
```

Alternatively, you could use `doOnSuccess` and check if `Mono` has completed without data(sample in Java):

```java
repository.findUser(name = "John Doe")
    .doOnSuccess(e -> {
      if (e == null) { 
        log.info("No user was found.");
      }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you! I like the `Mono.defer { }` as it's just less lines of code